# How can I create an undirected graph in ASP.NET Razor pages or in windows forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-structures, graph

I tried using some graphic libraries for generating graphs in MS Visual Studio 2022, but I have not been successful. I am also trying to populate the graph with the data coming from an adjacency matrix, but I am now stuck on how to generate the graph itself.

P.S. I am using C# for this.

This is what I tried to do in the pages' view.
I also used a little bit of JavaScript with the help of ChatGPT, but nothing worked so far.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spider Diagram</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        svg {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-opacity: 0.6;
        }

        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node text {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
    <script>
        var matrix = [
            [null, 1, 1, null, null],
            [1, null, 1, 1, null],
            [1, 1, null, 1, null],
            [null, 1, 1, null, 1]
            [null, null, null, 1, null]
        ];

        var width = 960,
            height = 600,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 5;

        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

        var data = {
            nodes: [],
            links: []
        };

        // Create nodes
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            var node = {
                id: i + 1
            };
            data.nodes.push(node);
        }

        // Create links
        for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j]) {
                    var link = {
                        source: i + 1,
                        target: j + 1,
                        value: matrix[i][j] // add the value property here
                    };
                    data.links.push(link);
                }
            }
        }


        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

        var force = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

        var link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });


        var node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("g");

        var circles = node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); })
            .call(drag(force));

        var labels = node.append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d.id; })
            .attr("dx", 10)
            .attr("dy", ".35em");

        node.append("title")
            .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

        force
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked);

        force
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .alphaTarget(1)
            .restart();

        function ticked() {
            link
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

            node
                .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        }

        function drag(simulation) {
            function dragstarted(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(event, d) {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            }

            function dragended(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }

            return d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spider Diagram</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        svg {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-opacity: 0.6;
        }

        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node text {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script>
        var data= {
            "nodes":[
                {"id":0,"label":"Myriel"},
                {"id":1,"label":"Napoleon"},
                {"id":2,"label":"MlleBaptistine"},
                {"id":3,"label":"MmeMagloire"},
                {"id":4,"label":"CountessDeLo"},
                {"id":5,"label":"Geborand"},
                {"id":6,"label":"Champtercier"},
                {"id":7,"label":"Cravatte"},
                {"id":8,"label":"Count"},
                {"id":9,"label":"OldMan"},
                {"id":10,"label":"Labarre"}
                ],
            "links":[
                {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
                {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
                {"source":3,"target":0,"value":10},
                {"source":3,"target":2,"value":6},
                {"source":4,"target":0,"value":1},
                {"source":5,"target":0,"value":1},
                {"source":6,"target":0,"value":1},
                {"source":7,"target":0,"value":1},
                {"source":8,"target":0,"value":2},
                {"source":9,"target":0,"value":1}
                ]
            }


        var width = 960,
            height = 500,
            radius = 6;

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .gravity(.05)
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(80)
            .size([width, height]);

        var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
            var color = d3.scale.category20();

            force
                .nodes(data.nodes)
                .links(data.links)
                .start();

            var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(data.links);

            var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(data.nodes);

            node.exit().remove();
            link.exit().remove();

            link.enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
                    if ("value" in d) {
                        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                });

            var groups = node.enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node");

            groups.append("circle").attr("r", function (d) {
                if ("id" in d) { return 5; }
                else { return 0; }
            })
                .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.value); })
                .call(force.drag);

            groups.append("text")
                .attr("dx", 12)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text("hi");

            node.selectAll("text")
                .text(function (d) {
                    if ("label" in d) {
                        return d.label;
                    } else {
                        return d.id;
                    }
                }
                );

            force.on("tick", function () {
                link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                    .attr("y1", function (d) {
                        return d.source.y;
                    })
                    .attr("x2", function (d) {
                        return d.target.x;
                    })
                    .attr("y2", function (d) {
                        return d.target.y;
                    });

                node.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });
                node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

I use the `V3` version to test, and there are changes to the `d3.scale.category20()` method in `V7`, you need to pay attention.

[Original Code](https://gist.github.com/mayblue9/32de2cafe6398eab61bbe318c3fbe360#file-script-js)

Comment: Hi @Finsser, will this code work in your code?